# Permission denied folder : /var/spool/cups

Tags: permissions, cups, spool

when i try run my script , is giving the message

" /var/spool/cups : Permission denied "

But , i try use this :

`chmod 777 /var/spool/cups`

but , dont work .

someone could help me ?

I have acess to root user .

Comment: Just a guess, but either the new cups is looking to a different place for it's spool directory than the old one did, or it's running as a different user. I think the next thing to check is what user cups is running as:

ps aux | grep cups

If that shows something other than "root", then you need to change the ownership of the directory to that user.

Comment: Use sudo to run the script: sudo /var/spool/cups

Comment: i am using Ibquota ( is a application server to control how many pages the user can print ) , i try sudo ibquota.pl , but dont work.

Comment: show this the " ps aux | grep cups " 


root      3111  0.0  0.1  76624  2916 ?        Ss   11:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -C /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
root      5023  0.0  0.0   7544   848 pts/1    S+   11:17   0:00 grep cups

Comment: Just to link this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1120256/how-to-monitor-and-copy-cups-spool-data-and-copy-files-to-run-a-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUPS will not let you have access there, even as root. This folder is accessible only by the printing agents CUPS allows. If you are trying to grab a postscript file from in there, you need to have a custom CUPS backend script move the file to another directory, so it can be handled there. Or you could have the CUPS backend script run the script you are trying to run, as long as it can run under those permissions.

[This link](http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=slackware:cups) has a great tutorial at the bottom on writing your own CUPS backend.